# Can't select Beer, Wine & Spirits on Data Explorer

Tags: support, bug, data-explorer

I can't select Beer, Wine & Spirits SE from the input field on https://data.stackexchange.com/.

The placeholder is "search by name or url" but:

- if I start typing `https://alcohol.stackexchange.com` or `alcohol.stackexchange.com` no option can be selected,
- if I type `Beer...` I can then select `Beer, Wine & Spirits Stack Exchange` but the url https://data.stackexchange.com/beer,%20wine%20&%20spirits%20stack%20exchange/query/new gives me a server error beginning with:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server...

- if try experimenting/editing the above url with - e.g. - `%2C` in place of `,` or other, I always get a 404.

Is there something wrong serverside or am I neglecting something? The Joomla! one is another **beta** SE site but it does not show the same problem, obviously not depending on the web browser I use.

Thank you!

Comment: Reproduced.  Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: In addition, correcting the URL to https://data.stackexchange.com/alcohol/query/new gives a 404

Comment: Oh, but if you then replace "alcohol" with "beer" in @ArtOfCode's URL, it works.  Beer was the original name (and URL) of the site; it looks like SEDE half-updated, offering the new *name* in the drop-down list but not updating the URL.  You can get there with manual editing, but yeah, we should fix this.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've seen it, it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Cross site duplicate on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296521/data-se-breaks-when-looking-things-up-on-beer-wine-and-spirits

Comment: I've bountied that MSE post in the hope it attracts enough SE eyes so someone might find the time to run that sql update statement.

Comment: @rene great, I see. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the & in the name of the site. The actual error thrown is:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

Here is my local reproduction of the error:

[image: error due to &]

The easiest fix for now to change the record for alcohol.se in Sites table as found the Data.StackExchange database. I don't fancy fiddling with [webserver settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Particularly I propose to change the Name column to `Beer, Wine and Spirits Stack Exchange` but keep the Longname column with the `&`. That change will still show the site name as we are used to, even in the site switcher:

[image: site switcher]

while it uses the value from the `Name` column to construct the url when you click that item.

A quick inspection didn't reveal any other serious mishaps with this change in place.

Now we need to bribe [someone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/taryn) with database access to execute this query on Data.StackExchange:

```
update sites 
set name = 'Beer, Wine and Spirits Stack Exchange'
where Id = 224 -- oh I hope these ids are stable ... please let them be 

update sites 
set name = 'Beer, Wine and Spirits Meta Stack Exchange'
where Id = 225 -- oh I hope these ids are stable ... please let them be
```